# how to use $in in mongo monk

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

what the equalent code of mongo for monk?

```
use challenger_documents
db.question.find({_id: {$in: [ObjectId("56587ad1c30ea73eb22546f0"), ObjectId("5659779b5eb5a70f35db8125")]}})
```

for example, i tried this but it returns []:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/challenger_documents');
question = db.get("question")
question.find({_id:{$in:["5659cba1ef72b7ef523206c5"]}},{},function(e,d){console.log(d)})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the `_id` string to an `ObjectId`:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb'),
    monk = require('monk'),
    db = monk('localhost:27017/challenger_documents'),
    ObjectId = mongodb.ObjectID,
    question = db.get("question");

question.find({_id: { $in: [ ObjectId("5659cba1ef72b7ef523206c5") ] } },{},function(e,d){ console.log(d) });
```